# Looker Studio: Upgrading Date Compatibility to Date clears out graphs or results in Failed to get data

Tags: date-formatting, looker

I have a dashboard in Looker Studio that is suddenly showing inaccurate data (it worked fine the day before).

I had added a column to a data source. When I reconnected the data source, I can see that the date format is showing the old date format, YYYYMMDD (I don't recall seeing that before).Previously the date format in this Google Sheet was formatted as Jan 2023 (01/01/2023 in the formula bar). I changed the format to MM/DD/YYYY. There were still inaccuracies in the graphs.

I tried to upgrade from Date Compatibility to Date and the graphs are blank or have an error message, see below.

[Date Compatibility/old date format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6TIa.png)

[Empty graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGOgI.png)

[Failed to get data message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdfJE.png)

I have one data source that is the old date format.

I upgraded from Date Compatibility (YYYYMMDD) to Date. The format in Google Sheets is MM/DD/YYYY.

The charts went blank or I received an error message "Failed to get data"

I then went into the date fields in the blend and in the chart, removed the old date fields and entered them in again.

The charts are either still empty or have the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced issues with date and datetime fields in a Google Sheets datasource, that seemingly appeared out of nowhere (worked fine before). Strange thin is, that we have a sync running in apps script. Sometimes the fields are recognized correctly, sometimes only as text...

Anyhow, try to use a different format in Google Sheets datasource:

- Date & Time -> Sep 15, 2020, 16:10:59:59
- Date -> Sep 15, 2020

[Custom date formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuYHd.png)